# Why is my getter magic method using a class instance as an index?

Tags: php, kohana

here's my getter:

```
public function __get($field)
    {
        if ($field == 'userId'):
            return $this->uid;
        else:
            return $this->fields[$field];
        endif;
    }
```

here's my constructor

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->uid = null;
        $this->fields = array(
            'username' => '',
            'password' => '',
            'firstname' => '',
            'lastname' => '',
            'email' => '',
            'is_active' => false
        );
            $this->session = Session::Instance();
            $this->profiler = new Profiler();
            $this->encrypt = new Encrypt();
    }
```

everytime i access this function:

```
private function handle_pass($password, $username=null, $encrypt=true)
    {
        if ($encrypt) :
            return $this->encrypt->encode($password);
        else:
            $query = ORM::factory('user');
            $result = $query
                ->select('password')
                ->where('username', $username)
                ->find();
            $compare_pass = $this->encrypt->decode($password);
            return ($compare_pass === $result->password);
        endif;
    }
```

i get this error

```
application/libraries/User.php: Undefined index: encrypt // this is the error message
application/libraries/User.php:User->__get( encrypt ) // this is the last method executed
```

Answer (score 1):

Is `encrypt` defined as a `public` variable in the class?  If not, the logic of your `__get()` function demands that it be read from `$this->fields['encrypt']`, which is never set, and is what's producing that error.

Comment: let's say I have an encrypt class I want to call from this class. How do I do that? I have tried $this->encrypt = new Encrypt but I guess the class interprets it as one of ist attributes.

Comment: Let's be clear: the `Encrypt` *class* is irrelevant here.  The problem is the `encrypt` (correctly lowercase) instance variable.  You must declare that property as either `public $encrypt;` or `protected $encrypt;` (depending on what visibility you want it to have).

Comment: $this->encrypt = new Encrypt() is perfectly valid. The encrypt property should be an instance of Encrypt.

Comment: Of course it's perfectly valid; I've made no claim to the contrary.  The property should still be declared as either `public` or `private`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [get_object_vars](http://php.net/get_object_vars) on the object before attempting to access the encrypt property to see if it really exists. Something else could be going on.

```
var_dump(get_object_vars($myClass));
```

Edit:

After looking at your code. The [get()](http://php.net/__get) method should never be called since it is only invoked when a referenced property is inaccessible. Are you declaring $encrypt as private? Are you declaring it at all? What makes you think [get()](http://php.net/__get) should be invoked? (Formatter goes crazy when I try to put underscores infront of get() with a link).

```
class myClass()
{
  public $encrypt;

  public function __construct() 
  {
    $this->encrypt = new Encrypt();
  }

  public function __get($property)
  {
    return $this->$property;
  }

  public function handle_pass()
  {
    $this->encrypt->decode(); 
    // Since $encrypt is public, __get() will not be invoked
  }
}
```

Comment: will do...but first i'll try adding the encryt class instantiation in the __get magic method...hope it works